# System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. GraphicsPath.AddString

Tags: c#, argumentexception

So I've been having this issue when debugging, I get an Access Violation, but when I run without the Debugger, I get an Error that tells me that A Parameter is invalid. It lead me to path.AddString(...); Any reason as to why? Honestly, all Parameters are correct, else the compiler would catch it. This is making me angry.

```
        protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs e )
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            if ( !extended )
            {
                setColor ( );
                g.FillRectangle ( new SolidBrush ( currColor ), this.ClientRectangle );
            }
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            string szbuf = Program.AppName;
            SolidBrush brushWhite = new SolidBrush ( Color.White );
            g.FillRectangle ( brushWhite, 0, 0,
            this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height );

            FontFamily fontFamily = this.Font.FontFamily;
            StringFormat strformat = StringFormat.GenericDefault;
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush ( Color.FromArgb ( 255, 255, 255 ) );

            SizeF sz = g.MeasureString(szbuf, this.Font);
            int w = ( ( this.Width / 2 ) - ( ( int ) sz.Width / 2 ) );
            int h = 10;
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath ( );
            float emSize = g.DpiY * this.Font.Size / 72;
            path.AddString ( szbuf, fontFamily, 0, 48f, new Point ( w, h ), strformat);

            for ( int i = 1; i < 8; ++i )
            {
                Pen pen = new Pen ( getColor ( ), i ); //Color.FromArgb ( 32, 0, 128,  192 ), i );
                pen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
                g.DrawPath ( pen, path );
                pen.Dispose ( );
            }

            g.FillPath ( brush, path );

            fontFamily.Dispose ( );
            path.Dispose ( );
            brush.Dispose ( );
            g.Dispose ( );
        }
```

Comment: "else the compiler would catch it" - this isn't generally true. The compiler can tell if you are passing the wrong type to something but if the type is correct but the value is wrong the compiler will not be able to tell. For example if you were creating an image and specifying x and y dimensions the compiler would see an int going in and be happy but if that int is `-1` then I would expect the method to break at runtime with an exception telling me that I passed an invalid value.

Comment: I should note I'm not saying that you are passing negative widths or anything like that, just addressing your misconceptiong on what the compiler is able to stop from happening. Maybe this will help you work out what is going on yourself.

Comment: Also a stacktrace is usually helpful to point at the exact line where things are going wrong. I assume this is what led you to the `path.AddString` call but it is sometimes good for us to see a full stacktrace and the actual exception type to aid in debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line:

```
fontFamily.Dispose();
```

You're disposing `this.Font.FontFamily` object. `Control` will be in an invalid state and next call to `Paint` will fail. You're also disposing `Graphics` object, do not do it because it may be used after your function.

In general you have to **dispose only objects you created**, nothing more and nothing less (creator owns responsibility to dispose that objects). Compiler can't catch this kind of errors (unless you run a static code analysis) because it's a run-time error caused by program execution path. If you're lucky you'll have an exception (`ArgumentException` because you're passing an invalid argument: a disposed font).

Moreover you don't need to call `Dispose()` explicitly, it's more safe to use `using` statement (it'll work also in case of exceptions). Let me **refactor little bit your code**:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    if (!extended)
    {
        setColor();
        using (var backgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(currColor))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(backgroundBrush, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }

    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    string szbuf = Program.AppName;

    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0,
        this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);

    StringFormat strformat = StringFormat.GenericDefault;

    SizeF sz = g.MeasureString(szbuf, this.Font);
    int w = ((this.Width / 2) - ((int)sz.Width / 2));
    int h = 10;

    using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        float emSize = g.DpiY * this.Font.Size / 72;
        path.AddString(szbuf, Font.FontFamily, 0, 48f, new Point(w, h), strformat);

        for (int i = 1; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            using (var pen = new Pen(getColor(), i))
            {
                pen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
                g.DrawPath(pen, path);
            }
        }

        g.FillPath(Brushes.White, path);
    }
}
```

Please note that to create resources for each paint isn't efficient (allowed but very slow). You should reuse them as much as possible (for example using a dictionary). Moreover for constant colors it's better to use predefined brushes (for example `Brushes.White`, do not dispose them). Let me show a very naive implementation (easy to extend to cache both `Pen` and `SolidBrush`):

```
private Dictionary<Color, SolidBrush> _solidBrushes;
private SolidBrush GetSolidBrush(Color color)
{
    if (_solidBrushes == null)
         _solidBrushes = new Dictionary<Color, SolidBrush>();

    if (!_solidBrushes.ContainsKey(color))
        _solidBrushes.Add(color, new SolidBrush(color));

    return _solidBrushes[color];
}
```

Then it'll be used like this:

```
if (!extended)
{
    setColor();
    g.FillRectangle(GetSolidBrush(currColor), this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to stop writing as if I was writing 7 years ago, it's a bad habit.